# Насколько корректна такая реализация фронтэнда в "боевых условиях"?

Tags: jquery, javascript, frontend

Привет.

По вашему мнению, будет ли считаться данная реализация фронтэнда хорошей практикой? Если можно, поясните почему да/нет.

```
var myApp = {
    'body':function(){
        // code for all pages
        console.log(['run it  on every page']);
    },
    '.page-index':function(){
        console.log(['run it only on index']);
    },
    '.page-contacts':function(){
        console.log(['run it only on contact page']);
    },
    '.video-link':function(){
        console.log(['run it where i has link on video']);        
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each(myApp,function(element,code){
        if ($(element).length) {
            code();
        }
    });
});
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/zm611pth/2/ )

Хочу получить:

- несложную модульность (не нравится require.js);
- зависимость выполнения js от html шаблонов;
- не "светить наверх" переменными и объектами;
- подтягивать тяжелые скрипты (типа Gmap3.js) при помощи `$.getScript();`.